# Two small non-normally distributed samples and one simple question

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

A great newbie in statistics, I am. Begging for your help, I am.
So, I have two samples. The first one contains 19 mean preference scores (based on a series of twelve 0s and 1s) and the second one contains 20 mean preference scores. Clearly, they do not follow a normal distribution and that is why I read that I should do a Wilcoxon test instead of Student test. OK. But R tells me that I have many ties for this test. Even if it is not an error message, I do not like warning messages. Not at all. So I was wondering if I could trust that results. And also, what do you think about changing the ties by some randomly chosen very very closed values? Like changing 0.7 by a random value chosen between 0.6999 and 0.7001? Can it do the trick?

Here are my samples:

```
Treatment   MeanPrefScore   Treatment   MeanPrefScore
Quick       0.5             Long        0.571428571
Quick       0.9             Long        0.777777778
Quick       0.916666667     Long        0.333333333
Quick       1               Long        0.666666667
Quick       0.714285714     Long        1
Quick       0.4             Long        1
Quick       0.888888889     Long        0.777777778
Quick       0.857142857     Long        0.857142857
Quick       1               Long        0.916666667
Quick       1               Long        1
Quick       1               Long        0.75
Quick       0.916666667     Long        0.916666667
Quick       0.5             Long        1
Quick       0.909090909     Long        0.909090909
Quick       0.571428571     Long        0.8
Quick       0.909090909     Long        0.75
Quick       0.8             Long        1
Quick       0.5             Long        0.5
Quick       0.545454545     Long        0.916666667
Quick       0.777777778
```

Here is what R tells me:

```
Result1 <- wilcox.test(MeanPrefScore ~ Treatment, data = MeanPrefScore)
Warning message: In wilcox.test.default(x = c(0.571428571, 0.777777778, 0.333333333,  : 
cannot compute exact p-value with ties

Result1
     Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
     data:  MeanPrefScore by Treatment
     W = 209, p-value = 0.6002
     alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

So any help, any explanation for a super simple quick to do test, would be infinitely appreciated!

Comment: Your mean preference scores are the proportion of 1's, so I'd be likely to use an analysis appropriate for a comparison of proportions. Both tests you mention should be adequate when done correctly, but I'd have used something specifically designed for count proportions. I note that you list a "long" score beside every "quick" score (apart from the last) -- are the two groups independent or does that layout indicate paired data? What does each "1" represent? For a given subject, does it make sense to regard them as being random draws with the same underlying probability ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... of a 1 for that subject, or will they vary? If you expect a subject's underlying  proportions to vary within each expression of a preference (e.g. preferences for different things), do you have the individual 0's and 1's for each subject?

Comment: Could you edit the title of your post to make it more informative? Now it reads a bit like a puzzle (a nice one on its own), which is not really appropriate as we look for questions and answers getting directly to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend modifying the data to eliminate ties.  I think the test result is fine as is. The message merely says that the exact p-value cannot be computed because of the ties.  But you do have an approximate p-value of 0.6002. This means the difference between the two mean preference scores is not statistically significant. Looking at the data this makes sense since in many cases the two results are exactly equal or nearly equal.

Comment: Hi Michael. If [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11032/michael-chernick) is your account, please consider [merging](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your present account with it.

Comment: Glen:  I haven't used my stackexchange account in four years.  I do not remember what email address I used then. So I cannot access it.  I don't think it would help me to merge my new account into the old one.  But if there is a way to merge the old account into the new one that would work for me.  Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: I don't know for sure if that can be done, but it can't hurt to use the contact form (see the link above) to ask to do so. If you can convince the community team the old account is yours (I imagine you may be able to, even without knowing the email account) they may even be prepared to tell you what email address is associated with it.

Comment: It's a privilege to have you back, Michael.  The account you used to use was your Yahoo email account.  It would help you to merge accounts because of the privileges that are associated with the old account.  Whether or not you intend to avail yourself of them, they do make using the site a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help guys. Here is an answer a bit more detailed and also what I decided to do.

So, I have 2 treatments, one quick to learn called `Quick` and the other long to learn called `Long`.

My goal is to see if my treatment `Long` changes the number of individuals able to learn a given task.

I have 40 individuals in 8 groups, with 4 group per treatment and 5 individuals per group. Each group does 60 trials. I look at each individual every 5 trials. At the end of the test, I end up with a list of 12 values per individual. These values are a list of failure `F` and success `S`.

Then, I want to see if an individual is more likely than random to get a `S`, i.e. is 6 `S` out of 12 significantly different from random? Is 9 `S` out of 12 significantly different from random? Etc...

Here is an example of the beginning of my dataset:

```
Group          Treatment          ID          Trial          Score
G1             Quick              Ind1        1              F
G1             Quick              Ind1        2              F
...            ...                ...         ...            ...
G1             Quick              Ind1        7              F
...            ...                ...         ...            ...
G1             Quick              Ind1        12             S
```

An example of the middle of my dataset:

```
G3             Quick              Ind14       1              F
G3             Quick              Ind14       2              F
...            ...                ...         ...            ...
G3             Quick              Ind14       5              S
...            ...                ...         ...            ...
G3             Quick              Ind14       12             S
```

And an example of the end of my dataset:

```
G8             Long               Ind40       1              S
G8             Long               Ind40       2              F
...            ...                ...         ...            ...
G8             Long               Ind40       8              S
...            ...                ...         ...            ...
G8             Long               Ind40       12             S
```

Then in R, I calculated the number of `S` for each individual:

```
Group          Treatment          ID          S
G1             Quick              Ind1        4
G1             Quick              Ind2        8
...            ...                ...         ...
G6             Long               Ind26       9
G6             Long               Ind27       3
...            ...                ...         ...
G8             Long               Ind39       12
G8             Long               Ind40       11
```

Then I groped for the minimum number of `S` required to get a significant p-value using `binom.test()`:

```
binom.test(1, 12, alternative = "greater")
binom.test(2, 12, alternative = "greater")
...
binom.test(10, 12, alternative = "greater")
```

I found that 10 `S` are required to get a significant p-value (`p = 0.01929`).

Then, I went back to my dataset summarizing the number of `S` of each individual. I found that 8 individuals have learned in the treatment `Quick` while 9 individuals have learned in the treatment `Long`.

I then did a chi squared table:

```
Observed values:
               Quick    Long    Total
Learned        8        9       17
Did not learn  12       10      22
Total          20       19      39

Theoretical values:
               Quick    Long    Total
Learned        8.7      8.3     17
Did not learn  11.3     10.7    22
Total          20       19      39
```

Now, I am wondering if it is correct to do a chi squared test in my case. I found online that I can do it if there is no cell value under 5 when I have a table with 1 degree of freedom (which is the case, right?). I also found 10. I read some things about a certain correction when cell values are between 5 and 10 but I did not understand well. I saw that a Fisher test is better in some cases. Basically, it is incredibly nebulous to me.

So please, I am begging your help. Enlighten me! :D